# PlacePicker open and close inmediatily november 2019

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

I'm Estiven this is my first question.

I trying to use PlacePicker. For get just the Address. But always when I make click in the buttom for open placepicker.

The placepicker open and close inmediatily. Some like that  i need (Select this location), here example:
https://ibb.co/HYD5TKP

My idea is get the address name y put this in EditText.

My API key is put in the manifest.xml.
So I have permission ubication enabled.

I  saw some developers say the PlacePicker just work to july 2019 in stackoverflow.

Here i found:
https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration

Place Picker
The Place Picker is deprecated as of January 29, 2019. This feature will be turned off on July 29, 2019, and will no longer be available after that date. You must install the compatibility library to continue using the Place Picker during the deprecation period. Once the deprecation period has ended, the Place Picker will no longer be available for use (including the version in the compatibility library).

So Google Places SDK is Depricated, I had migrate for new API "PLACES API" but same: The placepicker open and close inmediatily. Here the steps for migrate:
https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration

Or how i can get the address with PlacePicker some idea?

Best regards.

Comment: As per the very docs you have linked, you can't use Place Picker. It is gone forever. You should be able to do whatever it is you used to do in Place Picker by using the Places API.

Comment: now recently i found: PING Place Picker is here to help you to (almost) plug-and-play replace the original Google's Place Picker.

Comment: this work, open and don't close. But when select the location, show: 3° 45' 37" S, 73° 15' 7" E. i need get the address name. Here pingplacepicker: https://github.com/rtchagas/pingplacepicker in the page explain, how enable nearby searches, with this code: <bool name="enable_nearby_search">true</bool> but where put this code in manifest, activity? Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. Google Maps Places SDK for Android's *Place Picker* was already deprecated. As a workaround, you can create a PlacePicker using a combination of **Places SDK for Android** and **Maps SDK for Android**. To achieve the PlacePicker in your code, you can manually create [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete) as your search box  then feed the result in your map using [Maps SDK for Android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map-with-marker).

Additionally, Google is conducting a review on what drives the users to use the Place Picker, you can add your answer in the form mentioned in this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/128304760). To register your interest in this issue, you can also star it and it will subscribe you to receive technical updates regarding this issue.